# Double free or corruption error when using time.time() inside a pool worker subprocess

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I was running some basic tests to get a grasp of pool in Python when i got the error :

> Error in `/usr/bin/python3.5': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001adf380

with a full memory error stack and ending with :

> KeyError: 139961995958016

I was running the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x,t):
    print(time.time() - t)
    time.sleep(2)
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        time_start = time.time()
        l = [None]*4
        for i in range(4):
            l[i] = pool.apply_async(f, (10, time_start))

        l[-1].get(timeout=5*2)
        print(time.time()-time_start)
```

I don't really understand what happens here. It is related to the use of time.time() in the f function as commenting that line solves the issue but outside of that, i am at a loss.

I am running Python 3.5.2 (64 bits).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks you have found a bug in your Python implementation. That error is usually thrown by glibc when you try to `free` a pointer twice so there's no right reason for your Python code to be doing that.

Comment: Would that really qualify as a bug if this is the result of me not playing nice with multiprocessing and the time module ? Thing is i can't find any warning on the python documentation on the matter but i find it hard to believe i am the first one running into that issue as both modules are standards libraries.

Comment: IMHO it qualifies as a bug, the interpreter should be responsible for handling  all pointer-related madness. It may also be related to the way your distro compiles the interpreter and dependent libraries.